# Python xml.etree.ElementTree - how to reference the current node that I am parsing

Tags: python, xml, loops, parsing, elementtree

I have two python files that I am working with. In one file (file1.py) I begin a for loop that enters each main node in an XML file. In the other file (file2.py) I parse all of the necessary attributes that I use to create a few lists. These lists are then inserted into a MySQL database within a query in file1.py.

I am able to successfully parse every node in the XML file when I only loop through that node in file2.py. However, since I begin a loop in file1.py, I am not being able to reference the node I am in in file2.py. Here's an example that works on its own (please note: I'm leaving out parts of code on purpose as they are not important here):

```
 def get_info(self):
     for mainNode in self.mainNodes:
        self.values_list.append([mainNode.get(i) for i in list_of_attributes])
```

The above works fine because I start and end my loop all within the same function. However, how would I be able to reference the object "mainNode" if I started looping through self.mainNodes in another file? Is there I way that I can do something like:

```
 def get_info(self):
     self.values_list.append([CURRENT_NODE.get(i) for i in list_of_attributes])
```

?

In the other file I already declared that I am looping through self.mainNodes so my insert query executes once for each mainNode.

Also, I know that I can simply loop through self.mainNodes all in one file ( as I did in the first example) then make my insert query in another file. However, I'm re-assigning auto-incrementing primary IDs into other tables in a relational database by calling on MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID() function, so I need to loop through each main node and insert (not insert multiple rows at once) in order to successfully call on LAST_INSERT_ID() multiple times every time I execute my script.

Lastly, I cannot execute the function where I start my loop in file1.py within the function in file2.py because that will cause a cyclical dependency of modules and the script will break.

Sorry if any of this is worded in a strange way, I'm happy to edit the question to go into more detail if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you change `get_info`?  `def get_info(self,mainNode):`??

Comment: But then how would this file (file2.py) know that I am looping through mainNodes in file1.py? Can I call on that object without running the entire function that the object is created in?

Comment: Why does it need to?  Just call the `.get()` function on the node that is passed to the function.  It's much easier to figure out your goal if you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are correct that does work. Thanks for the responses @MarkTolonen if you submit as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the node you want to modify to the input parameters:

```
def get_info(self,node):
    self.values_list.append([node.get(i) for i in list_of_attributes])
```